Can removal of an electron be exothermic for anions?
Edit: I'm sorry, I still don't exactly understand the answer to my question. I thought there might have been some fundamental property that made removal of an electron from any species endothermic (similarly to how breaking bonds is always endothermic). Am I mistaken; can removal of an electron be exothermic?

I'm told that ionization energy is always positive (as in, removing an electron from a species always requires energy), since you're fighting against the attractive force of the nucleus. This was told to me as a fundamental law of nature: removing an electron from a species always requires energy, unlike a property like electron affinity, which can require or release energy. Some elements, such as nitrogen, have positive electron affinities (by which I mean, adding an electron to them requires energy). So the reaction
$N+e^- \rightarrow N^-$ has a positive $\Delta H$. I would think that would imply that the reverse reaction, $N^- \rightarrow N + e^-$, has a negative $\Delta H$ since it's simply the reverse of the enthalpy of the forward reaction. That seems to show that $N^-$ has a negative ionization energy (removing an electron releases energy). Is this true, or is there an error in my reasoning?
(I saw this: Why is ionization always an endothermic process?, but it didn't seem to directly answer my question.)

In your example, the process is not ionization, but deionization. It takes an ion and makes it an electrically neutral species.

So does that allow it to be exothermic?

I'm sorry, I still don't exactly understand the answer to my question. I thought there might have been some fundamental property that made removal of an electron from any species endothermic (similarly to how breaking bonds is always endothermic). Am I mistaken?

For some molecular entities, capturing an electron is endothermic and releasing it back is exothermic.

Related on the protonization side (potential well with high energy local minimum) :   Why doesn't H₄O²⁺ exist?  and  Can H4O^2+ form?

How will ionisation energy be exothermic? To remove an electron, you must add external energy to the atom, and whenever you add energy to an atom/molecule, it will always be endothermic. The bound electrons have lower energy than that of free electrons, making ionization energy always endothermic. In ionization, energy must be input to raise the particles to a higher energy level, making it an endothermic reaction.

The question is not about atoms, but anions, so I am afraid your initial unsupported assertion is irrelevant. Don't you think $N^{15-}$ would like to lose an electron or two?

But what is wrong with my argument that if electron affinity is endothermic, it means ionization energy of the anion must be exothermic, since it's simply the reverse reaction?

@unstable, maybe the problem is calling it ionization energy of the anion. In this context that name may cause confusion and is better calling it deiozation. Regarding the processes the change in entalphy, guess you reasoning is correct.
